# Align 3 <select> boxes in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My html is as follows  . I am using twitter bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well span4 pull-right">
    <s:bind path="month">
      <label class="control-label" for="month">Date of birth</label>
      <div class="control-group <c:if test="${status.error}">error</c:if>">
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            <form:select path="month" class="input-medium inline">
              <form:option value="">Month</form:option>
              <form:option value="1">January</form:option>
              ...
              <form:option value="12">December</form:option>
            </form:select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </s:bind>

    <s:bind path="day">
      <div class="control-group <c:if test="${status.error}">error</c:if>">
        <label class="control-label" for="day"></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            <form:select path="day" class="input-small">
              <form:option value="">Day</form:option>
              <form:option value="1" />
              ...
              <form:option value="31" />
            </form:select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </s:bind>

    <s:bind path="year">
      <div class="control-group <c:if test="${status.error}">error</c:if>">
        <label class="control-label" for="year"></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            <form:select path="year" class="input-small">
              <form:option value="">Year</form:option>
              <form:option value="2010" />
              ...
              <form:option value="1940" />
            </form:select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </s:bind>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently they are aligned as shown in the snapshot.

[image]

How i can align them in a row ?

Comment: use `display: inline-block` for `select`?

Comment: Use `select{float: left}` or `display: inline-block`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple solution would be to put them in a table!

```
    <table border="0">
<tr>
<td>

Select 1

</td>
<td>
Select 2

</td>
<td>

Select 3


 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Easy to do and works well!

Comment: Tried, tested, works! Maybe old school. But im all about the keep it simple stupid method!

Comment: Actually, all this not neeeded. `<select>` is already inline-block element. No need to put them neither into tables, nor into float blocks: they will be in one row without it. OP's problem is that `select`s are wrapped into unnecessary divs.

Comment: 0_o Maybe he wants " unnecessary divs " which in case would make them necessary!  No but regardless this way works just the same as removing every div, more or less its up to what he wants to do these are just diffrent options!

Comment: @nate Of course both ways work. I called divs unnecessary not because I don't like them, but because *such usage of them* they do not fit into Bootstrap's architecture that OP is using.  Divs with `.control-group` and `.control` Bootstrap's classes should **not** be placed into tables, it will cause many alignment problems. Instead, `.control` div defines the row in the form labeled by `label.control-label`. If we want cotrols in a row, why not put them into a container that is meant for it? *Anyway, mixing CSS framework with table layot never was a good idea.*

Comment: @nate, and of course, if you though that I offer to *remove divs entirely*, you misunderstood me, sorry for being vague. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14932423/693538) to see what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

Select is not a block-level element, so they would be in row without any floating if you **didn't wrap them into different divs and placed into the same div instead**.

Currently your structure is like this (shortened):

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
      <select>...</select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
      <select>...</select>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

If you instead put all `select`s into *the same `div.controls`*, you will get what you want:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
      <select>...</select>
      <select>...</select>
      ...
  </div>
</div>
```

If this still doesn't help, then probably there is some mess in your CSS styles. In this case ensure that your selects has inline-block display property by adding `select{display:inline-block}` to your CSS or setting `style` attribute on `select` tag itself: `<select style="display:inline-block">`

**UPD:** From the names of your classes I derive that you are trying to make a horizontal form. In this case meaning of classes is following:

- `<div class="control-group">` wraps the pair of *label* and *controls row*:

  - `<label class="control-label`> is the label of that row, it will be to the left
  - `<div class="controls">` is the row of contols that will be to the right of label

So, the div with `class="controls"` is meant by Bootstrap devs to be the row of controls. That's why if you want controls to be in a row — just put them all into this one div.

Also, you should wrap all your code into `<form class="form-horizontal>` in order to have proper margins and alignment. [Read the docs on Bootstrap forms](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) for more details.

Comment: I already know your solution but my issue is I have to show errors for this select boxes and if i put all div inside one controls how will show individual error because the error goes with the control-group class..

Comment: And i just using the css coming with twitter bootstrap and i have no other css from my side. SO i think it can't be mess.:)

Comment: I added <form:select path="year" class="input-small" style="display:inline-block"> but still they are in seperate row.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar, you don't need three separate `.control-group`s just for the sake of highlighting error. You can still have one control group with selects inside, and add `error` class to it if and only if any of three fields has error. Of course, in this case *all three* of them will be highlighted red. But **I'm sure that it's OK** since date validity is always determined by all three fields of it. *If, on the contrary, you want separate highlighting, you should forget the idea of placing contorls in one row. That is just how Bootstrap forms work: control groups are different rows, period.*

Comment: @SaurabhKumar but of course there's no rule that cannot be broken. If you add `style="display:inline-block"` or `style="float:left"` to `control-group` div, I think they will be staked on a line. But know that it is **a dirty, dirty hack** violating all Bootstrap layout principles. Expect anything: broken margins, staking one div on top of another, etc, etc. Bootstrap is made to make standard elements look nice. If you don't want them to be nice, why using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You could float the parent DIV (which is over all the selects) to left with CSS using:

```
float:left;
```

Greets
Marc